# Parsing a date which is a string from an rss feed and then displayed in a text view.

Tags: java, android, eclipse, datepicker

I am working on an app which parses an rss feed about roadworks into a list view and having difficulties parsing the date which is contained in a  tag, being a string. I have to use the date picker for when i enter a date it displays the necessary roadworks on that day.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have an example of the date as you receive it?

Comment: and what did you try so far ?

Comment: once data saved into your list. Get the data from date picker and then filter the data based on your date..

Comment: For example, if i enter the date 17/03/2014 it should display any roadworks on that day. So the date isnt a set date

Comment: You want DateFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

Comment: so far ive just got the basic date picker class but dont no what to change in order to solve my problem

Comment: We'll need to see a segment of the rss feed, the objects you're creating, your custom ArrayAdapter and any other pertinent code. Unless you can get more exact about what "isn't working".

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("17/03/2014");
System.out.println(date);
```

Here is the info on SimpleDateFormat for Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html